# Web Analytics Connector - Personalization String - how it should behave/render in the url?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I'm need some help understanding how a personalization string in a WAC attribute should actually render in the URL. Some scenarios (all sends are from Data Extensions):

**Valid string and valid value in source send list**

- WAC attribute is called *abcd*
- I use %%specialvalue%% in a WAC attribute
- specialvalue is a field in the source DE
- specialvalue has a value (ie is not null) for the recipient in the DE

This behaves as expected - the value from the DE renders properly in the URL

---

**Valid string but missing value in source send list**

- WAC attribute is called *abcd*
- I use %%specialvalue%% in a WAC attribute
- specialvalue is a field in the source DE
- specialvalue is blank/null for the recipient in the DE

Sometimes, the URL will render this as blank/null (eg: *www.site.com?abcd=*   ). But sometimes it renders as the literal personalisation string (eg:*www.site.com?abcd=%%specialvalue%%* )

**Why does it do that?**

---

**Invalid string (ie it is not a field in the DE)**

- WAC attribute is called *abcd*
- I use %%specialvalue%% in a WAC attribute
- specialvalue is NOT a field in the source DE

It renders as the literal personalisation string (eg:*www.site.com?abcd=%%specialvalue%%* ). But again, I would have thought it would either invalidate the send or simply be blank/null.

**Why does it do that?**

---

Thanks for any insights on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like OMM ignores the personalization string if it can't resolve at send time.

I would recommend using `%%=AttributeValue('specialvalue)=%%` instead. This function will return `null` if the attribute is not available in the data source context, and should resolve the behavior your are experiencing.

Comment: Looks like that worked. Thanks Eliot